# Confused about $x \notin x$ example in Axiom of Specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Halmos's *Naive Set Thoery*, I'm having a lot of problems in the Axiom of Specification. Halmos takes an example where a set $B$ is obtained from a set $A$ using the following specification:

$$B = \{x \in A : x \notin x \}$$

He then proceeds to prove that $B \notin A$.

While I'm still struggling with the proof, I have a more fundamental doubt here. Just a few lines ago he had argued that $A \notin A$ is an impossible set (which seems true enough), but doesn't the same reasoning apply to $x \notin x$? How can an element *ever* contain itself? It seems to me that because such a specification is impossible, it is absurd to derive any proof from it.

Please shed some light!

Comment: "$A \notin A$" is a truth value, not a set.

Comment: Yes, but $B$ is. And my point is that it seems absurd that $B$ be defined like this. In fact, intuitively, it seems as if $B = A$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gregkow's answer is not incorrect, but I think it doesn't get to the real issue. Namely, his answer uses the axiom of foundation which rules out self-membership outright; but we can ignore that axiom and allow self-membership consistently and find that specification will still prove that $B\notin A$.

Note that the central issue of Russel's paradox is that the Russel class, $R$, contains (or would contain if it existed) *every* set that's not a member of itself. We can use specification to show that $A$ must not contain *every* set of its members that aren't members of themselves, even if some of them *are* members of themselves.

Specification says that something is a member of $B$ if and only if it is in $A$ and not a member of itself. If $B$ is a member of itself then, by the definition of $B$, it must be in $A$ and not a member of itself; that's obviously contradictory. If $B$ is not a member of itself, then it must either be a member of itself *or* it's not in $A$; since the former would be paradoxical, it shows that $B$ exists and is not in $A$. One immediate consequence is that $A$ cannot contain its own power set.

Comment: And for once I'm not going to launch into an advertisement for NF!

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but damned if I say I can understand Russel's Paradox . . . my head is beginning to hurt!

Comment: If you know any proof methods for first order logic, I personally found it easier to wrap my head around a formal proof of contradiction from the single premise $\forall x(x\in R\iff x\notin x)$. It sounds funny in informal English, but a clear proof is like two lines long.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thanks. I don't have a huge amount of background in set theory, though I have read into it a fair bit. Nice answer!

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I did study *some* first-order logic some time back, but all this talk of sets within sets that contain or do not contain sets that contain/do not contain themselves, ad infinitum, is something I'm encountering the first time. So I guess it will take some time to break it down and digest.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that for every set $x$, $x\notin x$, then you know that for every element $x\in A$, $x\notin x$ and therefore $x\in B$. It follows immediately, if so, that $A=B$. So indeed $B\notin A$.

However proving that $A\notin A$ requires the axiom of regularity which is harder to justify naively, whereas proving that $B\notin A$ does not require that axiom.

What naive set theory usually proves (I am unfamiliar with Halmos' text, so it might not be the case here) is that there is no set "of all the sets which are not members of themselves", that is $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ is not a set. But this case $A$ is just any set and it may or may not be a member of itself, so the context differs.

Answer (score 2):

This is true, an element cannot be an element of itself. Thus, $\{x\in A:x\not\in x\}=A$, since $x\not\in x$ is always true. We then conclude $B=A$, so by what we had before, $B\not\in A$. It's not absurd to derive a proof from a true statement such as $x\not\in x$.

Comment: Yes, this is what also *appears* to be the case to me, but I think all the rigor in the book has some point to it. Unfortunately, Set Theory is beginning to give me headache. :D